# error while running the codeException in thread django-main-thread Traceback

Tags: django, web-applications

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 133, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 485, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 42, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 72, in _load_all_namespaces
    namespaces.extend(_load_all_namespaces(pattern, current))
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 72, in _load_all_namespaces
    namespaces.extend(_load_all_namespaces(pattern, current))
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 72, in _load_all_namespaces
    namespaces.extend(_load_all_namespaces(pattern, current))
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  [Previous line repeated 988 more times]
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 62, in _load_all_namespaces
    namespaces = [
                 ^
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

can anyone tell ma what can I do to solve it

Comment: Add your code, **urls.py** etc...  This is probably due to a url patter that is trying to include itself, thus generating the endless recursion.